# divergence form of the determinant

Tags: partial-differential-equations, determinant, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-derivatives

I'm having problems with the following question:

> Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ open and bounded. Let
>   $\{u^n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a bounded sequence in
>   $H_0^1(\Omega:\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that $u^n\rightharpoonup u$ in
>   $H_0^1(\Omega:\mathbb{R}^2)$. Show that for all $\phi\in
>  C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ \begin{equation}
>  \int_\Omega(\partial_1u_1^n\partial_2u_2^n-\partial_1u_2^n\partial_2u_1^n)\phi
>  dx\to\int_\Omega(\partial_1u_1\partial_2u_2-\partial_1u_2\partial_2u_1)\phi
>  dx  \end{equation}

**The hint is to write $\partial_1u_1^n\partial_2u_2^n-\partial_1u_2^n\partial_2u_1^n$ as a divergence.**

How would you see that as a divergence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\partial_1 u_{1}^{n} \partial_2 u_{2}^{n} - \partial_1 u_{2}^{n} \partial_2 u_{1}^{n}& = \partial_1 (u_{1}^{n} \partial_2 u_{2}^{n}) - \partial_2(u_{1}^{n} \partial_1 u_{2}^{n}) \\
 & = \text{div}(u_{1}^{n} \partial_2 u_{2}^{n}, -u_{1}^{n} \partial_1 u_{2}^{n})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

which is what you're after.